# Air - Launch app from browser not working in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome, air

I'm using a Flash based button to launch an Adobe Air desktop app from the browser.
It works across all browsers but not for Google Chrome. I don't receive any error messages.
Does anybody have an idea what the reason could be?

This is the JavaScript of SWFObject for embeding the .SWF:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};


            params.bgcolor="#FFFFFF"; 
            params.menu="false"; 
            params.quality="high"; 
            params.scale="noscale"; 
            params.wmode="window"; 
            params.allowscriptaccess="always"; 
            params.allowfullscreen="true"; 

            attributes.name = "";
            attributes.styleclass = "";
            attributes.align = "";          
            swfobject.embedSWF("swf/launchapp.swf?v=1", "flashContent", "480", "500", "9.0.115", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
```

This is the AS3 code:

```
var swfloader:Loader;
var airtarget:Object;

var appID:String = "com.example.desktop"; 
var pubID:String = ""; 

function loadAirSWF(e:Event=null):void 
{
    swfloader = new Loader();
    var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    swfloader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
    swfloader.load(new URLRequest("http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf"), loaderContext);
btnsend.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClicked);
    }

function onInit(e:Event):void
{
airtarget = e.target.content;
}


function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var appLaunchArg =  [txtArray]; 
airtarget.launchApplication("com.example.desktop", "", appLaunchArg)
}

loadAirSWF();
```

Thanks you. Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Adobe AIR and Google Chrome.  This has been ongoing since August 2012.  More information about this issue is available from the following links:

[Adobe Forums - Problem with badge installation in Chrome on Windows](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4603664#4603664)

[Bug listing with Google](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140854)

[Bug listing with Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3310921)